# Galaxy S4 will not display borders in any browser

Tags: android, html, css, border, galaxy

I am having problems displaying borders in chrome on the Galaxy S4.

```
.border {
width: 49vw;
border-width: .25vw;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
display: block;
}
```

I can't find any problems with the code. I do know that there are also problems with border-radius, however, I don't think these two things relate.
UPDATE:
I just learned that the border will show up in landscape mode, but will not in portrait.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Do borders appear if you specify the width in `px`?

Comment: @Timmah Not it portrait. I just learned that it works perfectly (in both vw, and px) in landscape, but it does not in portrait.

Comment: what about stupidly high border thicknesses i.e. `border: solid 10px red;` to ensure it isn't being lost in the high-DPI screen? I have experienced similar issues with iPhone retina displays. I'd try a really obvious border in both views to be sure.

Comment: @Timmah That worked!!! Thanks! Now I just have to find a way to use it with the viewport width. EDIT: Nevermind, I had to increase the vw number, so it wouldn't be displayed as part of a pixel! Thank you for all of your help!!!

Comment: No worries. A little testing saves a lot of wasted time eh!